# Should Jquery Component return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I am trying to create a jquery module with BDD(Behavior-driven development).

Here is my component

```
(function($) {
    function MyModule(element){
        return false;        
    }

    $.fn.myModule = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return this.each(function() {
            new MyModule(this);
        });
    };

    $.fn.myModule.Constructor = MyModule;

})(window.jQuery);
```

Here is my test

```
QUnit.test( "test", function( assert ) {
    assert.expect(1);

    var smallBox = $('<div/>',{'id':'smallBox'}).width(200).height(200);
    var result = smallBox.myModule();
    console.log(result); // This gives the HTML element itself but I am expecting it must be boolean false
    assert.notOk(result, "should return false" );
});
```

[HERE IS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/09zecyvj/)

**I have 2 questions.**

1- What if my component returns boolean. Is it wrong pattern?

2- How I can return boolean from my component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're not returning `new MyModule`, you're returning the returned value of `this.each` which is a jQuery object. If you want a boolean you'll have to return a boolean. Like this:

```
$.fn.myModule = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    this.each(function() {   // don't return here because then you'll return a jQuery object
        new MyModule(this);
    });

    return false;            // return a boolean (works)
};
```

**Returning from inside the callback is not affecting the returned value of the parent function.**

Comment: so validation should be inside $.fn.myModule

Comment: @MehmetErenYener Yes you should accumulate the result of all the `new MyModule` calls and then return that value.